# Can pause frames be forwarded through a layer 2 managed switch?

Tags: ethernet, switching, layer2

I'm not sure this question needs much detail.

I have two Linux hosts connected to a switch with 10 ports. One host has a 10 GbE NIC and the other host has a 1 GbE NIC. Obviously I can flood the 1 GbE card with udp packets. I enable symmetric flow control on the switch for both ports and "as far as I know" have enabled it on the host NICs.

The question now is, when 1 GbE cannot keep up he sends a pause frame to the switch. From what I see, a pause frame can only go Mac-to-Mac.

**Therefore, the switch does not forward the pause frame to the host that is pounding the network with traffic. Is that statement true?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pause frame can be MAC-to-MAC which is host-to-host through a switch. It can also be sent to a special multicast address which a switch will not forward, but the switch itself may or may not participate in ethernet flow control.

The use of ethernet flow control is implementation specific, and not widely or consistently supported. The way it works, or doesn't, on your network is going to be dependent on your network equipment and the software on those devices, and the specific hosts and OSes of the end devices.

Comment: So from your statement, a switch will not forward a pause frame. Essentially, one host cannot tell the other host to pause, using the switch as a hop. A host can only tell the switch to pause and stop sending to myself (the host) .

Comment: That's not what I said. A pause frame sent to a host MAC address will be forwarded by a switch. A pause frame sent to the special multicast address will not be forwarded by a switch since it is meant for the link. The switch may or may not participate in ethernet flow control, so the pause frames sent to the MAC address may or may not be acted upon by the switch. If your host only generates multicast pause frames, the other host will never get them, and a switch which doesn't participate will ignore them.

Comment: Sorry you were quite clear as I misunderstood. How could a switch not participate? If two hosts are only connected via "the switch", the switch would have to participate and forward to the host MAC address if specified as the destination address (rather than the multicast address)?

Comment: Of course the switch participates in the forwarding of frames. What it may or may not participate in is ethernet flow control. Pause frames sent to the special multicast MAC address will not be forwarded off the link from the host to the switch, but the switch may not be configured to, or even support, ethernet flow control. If your host only generates multicast pause frames, it can't get to the other host, only the switch, and if the switch ignores the pause frames, you get no flow control.

Comment: @user_ABCD, the end result is that ethernet flow control is poorly supported, and it should never be counted upon. It may be useful if it works, but it takes the correct equipment and the correct type of pause frames for your equipment and what you want to do.

Comment: Definitely understandable. My switch does support symmetric flow control. Last question, how do you know if your host (say Linux pc) generates only multicast pause frames?

Comment: I suppose Wireshark will be able to tell you.

Comment: @RonMaupin you said "if host generates multicast multicast pause frames, the other host will never get them"- so how other host will get to know that the receiver side have overflowed and now receiver is requesting to stop sending frame for some time?